# Open CV For Java : Can't find mat.dump() in the library

Tags: opencv

I'm using the org.bytedec.javacpp.presets Library for opencv and I cannot find the function mat.dump() in the library. It's extremely difficult to track functions in various tutorials and even in the documentation half of the functions are not available.

Any alternatives for that library?

Comment: Why are you using this library instead of opencv?

Comment: Mat.release() should also satisfy your needs [But be careful](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14285/how-to-free-memory-through-cvmat/)

Comment: Note that `Mat.dump()` and `Mat.release()` do completely different things: `Mat.dump()` creates a string representation of the data contained in the Mat and `Mat.release()` releases the memory occupied by the Mat.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use OpenCV directly, without any unnecessary wrappers. If you are developing for Android, I would recommend that you use [OpenCV built by Quickbird Studios](https://github.com/QuickBirdEng/opencv-android) as they offer versions compiled with and without the contrib modules. However, their package only works on Android. If you are using Java on any other platform, I would rather recommend [OpenCV packaged by OpenPnP](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv). The disadvantage is that this distribution does not include the contrib modules, but it works on any platform where the JVM runs on.

Note of affiliation: I am not affiliated with OpenPnP. I used to work for Quickbird Studios but am now not affiliated anymore as well.